# Luke Skywalker (injured?) stranded aboard a large automated spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, novel

I remember reading a story probably about 18 years ago in which Luke is stuck aboard some kind of automated freighter. I say automated, but there is some kind of ghost piloting it (or at least inside the system). Either Luke himself or maybe a companion is pretty seriously injured at the start of the book. There might also have been some kind of large fight taking place on the ship between the guards/crew. It was probably not the first book in its arc either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [Children of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Jedi_(novel)), although I do not remember Luke being injured at the start of the story (I have not read the story in some time, so I could have forgotten that).

In the story, Luke and some of his Jedi Knights boarded an old automated Imperial Ship in an effort to prevent it from destroying a planet.  When they get there, they find that the ship also contains the spirit of a Jedi Knight who had sacrificed herself to stop the ship initially.

Luke's Jedi companions are killed destroying the ship, but he manages to save the spirit of the trapped Jedi Knight (and falls in love with her) and she takes the body of one of his dead companions.

The battle you remember is probably the fighting between the occupants of the ship, who were not the crew but people from various species (I specifically remember Gamorreans, but I am pretty sure there were others as well) that were taken aboard the ship by the automated systems of the ship.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing things there but if I remember correctly and we both think about the same story it happened before he began training people (he was the only jedi that went on board as far as I remember.....the spirit was a trapped jedi knight though)

Comment: @Thomas I know at least one of the companions was a female Jedi because she gave up her body for the trapped Jedi spirit.

Comment: ah ok then my memory was faulty there (almost a decade since I read that book). tnx !

Comment: @Thomas this book takes place AFTER the Jedi Academy trilogy, so Luke would have had students now.